# TFlearn to categorical

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I`m using DNN of tflearn, and I want to change my features and lables to be categorical and not numeric.

here is my net:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.float32, shape=[None, 6], name='x')
# Build neural network
input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = input_layer
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 64, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 16, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='sigmoid')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='mean_square', metric='R2')

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[2]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(net, w) + b, name='y')

model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
return model
```

I know about tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical but I dont know how to inject this method.
thanks

**EDIT:**
I tried few things, like:

```
train_goal = tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical(train_goal, nb_classes=2)
            test_goal = tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical(test_goal, nb_classes=2)
```

and also change the loss:

```
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adadelta',  loss='categorical_crossentropy', metric= self.accuracy)
```

but I got loss more than 1:

```
Training Step: 35  | total loss: 1.64734 | time: 1.322s
| AdaDelta | epoch: 001 | loss: 1.64734 - acc: 1.0000 | val_loss: 1.64313 - val_acc: 1.0000 -- iter: 2204/2204
--
Training Step: 70  | total loss: 1.61961 | time: 0.216s
| AdaDelta | epoch: 002 | loss: 1.61961 - acc: 1.0000 | val_loss: 0.00000 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 2204/2204
--
Training Step: 105  | total loss: 1.58511 | time: 1.188s
| AdaDelta | epoch: 003 | loss: 1.58511 - acc: 1.0000 | val_loss: 1.57300 - val_acc: 1.0000 -- iter: 2204/2204
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error, also a very high loss.
Try use train_goal.T[0] instead of train_goal.
Make sure the input y for to_categorical has a shape like (n,)